# REQENV and SETIF If statement isn't evaluating correctly

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, regex

....or it is and I've missed something.

So I have a website that can only be accessed via certain IPs. A new development is that I want some of the pages on the site to be open and freely available to everyone regardless of IP - lets say www.mywebsite/opendir/coolstuff and www.mywebsite/opendir/morecoolstuff

To that end I have the following in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=REQUEST_URI:%{REQUEST_URI}]

SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "opendir.*$" REQUIREAUTH=false

<If "reqenv('REQUIREAUTH') != 'false'">
   # Require authentication for external access
    AuthName "Please Log In"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserfile /path/to/pswd
    Require valid-user
    Require ip 1.1.1.1
    Require ip 2.2.2.2
    Require ip 3.3.3.3
 </If>
```

I've been on this for hours. My phpinfo is showing that the REQUEST_URI is set correctly. My major niggle is that it is a dynamic URL CMS but I'm sure I've done all I can around that.

Put me out of my misery.

Edit. The full .htaccess is here minus my amendments

```
#################################################################################################
# START PROCESSWIRE HTACCESS DIRECTIVES
# @version 3.0
# @htaccessVersion 301
#################################################################################################
#
# Upgrading htaccess (or index) version 300 to 301
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# If you never modified your previous .htaccess file, then you can simply replace it with this
# one. If you have modified your .htaccess file, then you will want to copy/paste some updates
# to the old one instead:

# If your htaccess/index version is 300, upgrade to this version by replacing all of sections #5
# and #15 (Access Restrictions). Also take a look at section #9, which you might also consider 
# replacing if using HTTPS, though it is not required. (For instance, HSTS might be worthwhile)
# 
# Following that, optionally review the rest of the file to see if there are any other changes 
# you also want to apply. Sections tagged "(v301)" are new or have significant changes. 
# 
# When finished, add a line at the top identical to the "htaccessVersion 301" that you see at 
# the top of this file. This tells ProcessWire your .htaccess file is up-to-date. 
# 
# Resolving 500 errors
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Depending on your server, some htaccess rules may not be compatible and result in a 500 error.
# If you experience this, find all instances of the term "(500)" in this file for suggestions on
# things you can change to resolve 500 errors.
#
# Optional features
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Many of the rules in this .htaccess file are optional and commented out by default. While the
# defaults are okay for many, you may want to review each section in this .htaccess file for
# optional rules that you can enable to increase security, speed or best practices. To quickly
# locate all optional rules, search this file for all instances of "(O)". 
#
# If using a load balancer
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# If using a load balancer (like those available from AWS) some htaccess rules will need to 
# change. Search this file for instances of "(L)" for details. 
#


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 1. Apache Options 
#
# Note: If you experience a (500) error, it may indicate your host does not allow setting one or
# more of these options. First try replacing the +FollowSymLinks with +SymLinksifOwnerMatch.
# If that does not work, try commenting them all out, then uncommenting one at a time to 
# determine which one is the source of the 500 error. 
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Do not show directory indexes (strongly recommended)
Options -Indexes

# Do not use multiviews (v301)
Options -MultiViews

# Do follow symbolic links
Options +FollowSymLinks
# Options +SymLinksifOwnerMatch

# Character encoding: Serve text/html or text/plain as UTF-8
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 2. ErrorDocument settings: Have ProcessWire handle 404s 
#
# For options and optimizations (O) see: 
# https://processwire.com/blog/posts/optimizing-404s-in-processwire/
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 3. Handle request for missing favicon.ico/robots.txt files (no ending quote for Apache 1.3)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<Files favicon.ico>
  ErrorDocument 404 "The requested file favicon.ico was not found.
</Files>

<Files robots.txt>
  ErrorDocument 404 "The requested file robots.txt was not found.
</Files>


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 4. Protect from XSS with Apache headers
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # prevent site from being loaded in an iframe on another site
  # you will need to remove this one if you want to allow external iframes
  Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN 

  # To prevent cross site scripting (IE8+ proprietary)
  Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"

  # Optionally (O) prevent mime-based attacks via content sniffing (IE+Chrome)
  # Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" 
</IfModule>


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 5. Prevent access to various types of files (v301)
#
# Note that some of these rules are duplicated by RewriteRules or other .htaccess files, as we
# try to maintain two layers of protection when/where possible. 
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# 5A. Block access to inc, info, info.json/php, module/php, sh, sql and composer files
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<FilesMatch "\.(inc|info|info\.(json|php)|module|module\.php|sh|sql)$|^\..*$|composer\.(json|lock)$">
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>


# 5B. Block bak, conf, dist, ini, log, orig, sh, sql, swo, swp, ~, and more
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<FilesMatch "(^#.*#|\.(bak|conf|dist|in[ci]|log|orig|sh|sql|sw[op])|~)$">
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     Require all denied
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 6. Override a few PHP settings that can't be changed at runtime (not required)
# Note: try commenting out this entire section below if getting Apache (500) errors.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc     off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase      off
  php_flag register_globals     off
</IfModule>


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 7. Set default directory index files
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 8. Enable Apache mod_rewrite (required)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
 
  
  # 8A. Optionally (O) set a rewrite base if rewrites are not working properly on your server.
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # In addition, if your site directory starts with a "~" you will most likely have to use this.
  # https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
 
  # Examples of RewriteBase (root and subdirectories): 
  # RewriteBase /
  # RewriteBase /pw/
  # RewriteBase /~user/

  
  # 8B. Set an environment variable so the installer can detect that mod_rewrite is active.
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Note that some web hosts don't support this. If you get a (500) error, try commenting out this 
  # SetEnv line below. 

  <IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
  </IfModule>


  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # 9. Optionally Force HTTPS (O) 
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Note that on some web hosts you may need to replace %{HTTPS} with %{ENV:HTTPS} in order
  # for it to work (in sections 9A and 9D below). If on a load balancer or proxy setup, you will
  # likely need to use 9B rather than 9A, and 9E rather than 9D.  
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  # 9A. To redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS, uncomment the lines below (also see note above):
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  # RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


  # 9B. If using load balancer/AWS or behind proxy, use the following rather than 9A above: (L)
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http 
  # RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  
  # 9C. If using cPanel AutoSSL or Let's Encrypt webroot you may need to MOVE one of the below
  # lines after the first RewriteCond in 9A or 9B to allow certificate validation:
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[\w-]+$
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
 
  
  # 9D. Store current scheme in a 'proto' environment variable for later use
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
  RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:https]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:http]
  
 
  # 9E. If using load balancer/AWS or behind proxy, use lines below rather than 9D: (L)
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https 
  # RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:https]
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http 
  # RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:http]
 
  
  # 9F. Tell web browsers to only allow access via HSTS: Strict-Transport-Security (O) (v301)
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # This forces client-side SSL redirection. Before enabling be absolutely certain you can 
  # always serve via HTTPS because it becomes non-revokable for the duration of your max-age. 
  # See link below for details and options (note 'max-age=31536000' is 1-year):
  # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security
  
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Uncomment one (1) line below & adjust as needed to enable Strict-Transport-Security (HSTS):
    # Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;"
    # Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains"
    # Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; preload"
    # Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
  </IfModule>


  # Section 10 intentionally omitted for future use
 
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # 11. Nuisance blocking/firewall
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # None of these are enabled by default, but are here for convenience when the need arises.
  # Review and uncomment as needed. For more complete firewall (and more overhead), the 7G firewall
  # (or latest version) is worth considering, see: https://perishablepress.com/7g-firewall/
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
  # 11A. Block via IP addresses
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Note that IP addresses here are examples only and should be replaced with actual IPs.
  
  # Block single IP address
  # Deny from 111.222.333.444
  
  # Block multiple IP addresses
  # Deny from 111.222.333.444 44.33.22.11
  
  # Block IP address ranges (999.88.*, 99.88.77.*, 1.2.3.*)
  # Deny from 999.888 99.88.77 1.2.3
  
  # 11B. Block via request URI (matches strings anywhere in request URL)
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (bad-word|wp-admin|wp-content) [NC]
  # RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
      
  # 11B. Block via user agent strings (matches strings anywhere in user-agent)
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (bad-bot|mean-bot) [NC]
  # RewriteRule .* - [F,L]  
  
  # 11C. Block via remote hosts 
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} (bad-host|annoying-host) [NC]
  # RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
  
  # 11D. Block via HTTP referrer (matches anywhere in referrer URL)
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (bad-referrer|gross-referrer) [NC]
  # RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
  
  # 11E. Block unneeded request methods (only if you do not need them)
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(connect|debug|delete|move|put|trace|track) [NC]
  # RewriteRule .* - [F,L]  
  
  # 11F. Limit file upload size from Apache (i.e. 10240000=10 MB, adjust as needed)
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # LimitRequestBody 10240000
  
 
  
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # 12. Access Restrictions: Keep web users out of dirs or files that begin with a period,
  # but let services like Lets Encrypt use the webroot authentication method.
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  RewriteRule "(^|/)\.(?!well-known)" - [F]


  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # 13. Optional domain redirects (O)
  # 
  # Redirect domain.com to www.domain.com redirect (or www to domain.com redirect). 
  # To use, uncomment either 13A, 13B or 13C. Do not use more than one of them. 13A and 13B 
  # redirect non-www hosts to www.domain.com, 13C redirects www.domain.com host to domain.com.
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  # 13A. Redirect domain.com and *.domain.com to www.domain.com (see also 13B as alternate):
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
  # RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=::1
  # RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:PROTO}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  
  # 13B. Alternate www redirect if 13A does not work for your server: 
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:PROTO}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 
  # 13C. Redirect www.domain.com to domain.com (do not combine with 13A or 13B):
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:PROTO}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  # 14. Optionally send URLs with non-ASCII name-format characters to 404 page (optimization).
  # 
  # This ensures that ProcessWire does not spend time processing URLs that we know ahead of time
  # are going to result in 404s. Uncomment lines below to enable. (O)
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "[^-_.a-zA-Z0-9/~]"
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?it=/http404/ [L,QSA]


  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # 15. Access Restrictions (v301)
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  # 15A. Keep http requests out of specific files and directories
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  # Prevent all the following rules from blocking images in site install directories 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^|/)site-[^/]+/install/[^/]+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|svg)$
  
  # Block access to any htaccess files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(\.htaccess|htaccess\..*)$ [NC,OR]
  
  # Block access to various assets directories
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/assets/(cache|logs|backups|sessions|config|install|tmp)($|/.*$) [NC,OR]
  
  # Block access to the /site/install/ directories
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/install($|/.*$) [NC,OR]
  
  # Block dirs in /site/assets/dirs that start with a hyphen (see config.pagefileSecure)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/assets.*/-.+/.* [NC,OR]
  
  # Block access to /wire/config.php, /site/config.php, /site/config-dev.php, /wire/index.config.php, etc.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(wire|site|site-[^/]+)/(config|index\.config|config-dev)\.php($|/) [NC,OR]
  
  # Block access to any PHP-based files in /site/templates-admin/ or /wire/templates-admin/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(wire|site|site-[^/]+)/templates-admin($|/|/.*\.(php|html?|tpl|inc))($|/) [NC,OR]
  
  # Block access to any PHP or markup files in /site/templates/ or /site-*/templates/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/templates($|/|/.*\.(php|html?|tpl|inc))($|/) [NC,OR]
  
  # Block access to any files in /site/classes/ or /site-*/classes/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/classes($|/.*) [NC,OR]
  
  # Block access to any PHP files within /site/assets/ and further
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/assets($|/|/.*\.ph(p|ps|tml|p[0-9]))($|/) [NC,OR]
  
  # Block access to any PHP, module, inc or info files in core or core modules directories
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)wire/(core|modules)/.*\.(php|inc|tpl|module|info\.json)($|/) [NC,OR]
  
  # Block access to any PHP, tpl or info.json files in /site/modules/ or /site-*/modules/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/modules/.*\.(php|inc|tpl|module|info\.json)$ [NC,OR]
  
  # Block access to any software identifying txt, markdown or textile files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(COPYRIGHT|INSTALL|README|htaccess)\.(txt|md|textile)$ [NC,OR]
  
  # Block potential arbitrary backup files within site directories for things like config
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/(config[^/]*/?|[^/]+\.php.*)$ [NC,OR]
  
  # Block access throughout to temporary files ending with tilde created by certain editors
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(html?|inc|json|lock|module|php|py|rb|sh|sql|tpl|tmpl|twig)~$ [NC,OR]
  
  # Block access to names of potential backup file extensions within wire or site directories
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)(wire/|site[-/]).+\.(bak|old|sql|sw[op]|(bak|php|sql)[./]+.*)[\d.]*$ [NC,OR]
  
  # Block all http access to the default/uninstalled site-default directory
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^|/)site-default/
  
  # If any conditions above match, issue a 403 forbidden
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]

 
  # 15B. Block archive file types commonly used for backup purposes (O)
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # This blocks requests for zip, rar, tar, gz, and tgz files that are sometimes left on servers
  # as backup files, and thus can be problematic for security. This rule blocks those files 
  # unless they are located within the /site/assets/files/ directory. This is not enabled by 
  # default since there are many legitimate use cases for these files, so uncomment the lines 
  # below if you want to enable this.

  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(zip|rar|tar|gz|tgz)$ [NC]
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^|/)(site|site-[^/]+)/assets/files/\d+/ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]


  # PW-PAGENAME
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  # 16A. Ensure that the URL follows the name-format specification required by PW
  # See also directive 16b below, you should choose and use either 16a or 16b. 
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/~?[-_.a-zA-Z0-9/]*$"
  
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  # 16B. Alternative name-format specification for UTF8 page name support. (O)
  # If used, comment out section 16a above and uncomment the directive below. If you have updated 
  # your $config->pageNameWhitelist make the characters below consistent with that. 
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/~?[-_./a-zA-Z0-9æåäßöüđжхцчшщюяàáâèéëêěìíïîõòóôøùúûůñçčćďĺľńňŕřšťýžабвгдеёзийклмнопрстуфыэęąśłżź]*$"
  
  # END-PW-PAGENAME
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # 17. If the request is for a file or directory that physically exists on the server,
  # then don't give control to ProcessWire, and instead load the file
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)

  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # 18. Optionally (O) prevent PW from attempting to serve images or anything in /site/assets/. 
  # Both of these lines are optional, but can help to reduce server load. However, they
  # are not compatible with the $config->pagefileSecure option (if enabled) and they 
  # may produce an Apache 404 rather than your regular 404. You may uncomment the two lines
  # below if you don't need to use the $config->pagefileSecure option. After uncommenting, test
  # a URL like domain.com/site/assets/files/test.jpg to make sure you are getting a 404 and not
  # your homepage. If getting your homepage, then either: do not use this option, or comment out 
  # section #2 above that makes ProcessWire the 404 handler. 
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|webp|svg)$ [NC]
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(^|/)site/assets/

  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  # 19. Pass control to ProcessWire if all the above directives allow us to this point.
  # For regular VirtualHosts (most installs)
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?it=$1 [L,QSA]

  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  # 20. If using VirtualDocumentRoot (500): comment out the one above and use this one instead
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?it=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

#################################################################################################
# END PROCESSWIRE HTACCESS DIRECTIVES
#################################################################################################
```

Comment: What other directives do you have in your .htaccess file? Specifically with regards to mod_rewrite - which I assume is how these “dynamic URL CMS” are being routed?

Comment: Ones that prevent access to various types of files - sql etc, http to https, rules that lock certain directories down, robots txt. Nothing overly concerning and I've moved it around the file.

Comment: Please update your question with the contents of your `.htaccess` file. Specifically, I'm interested in the mod_rewrite directives (used to route your URLs). It's not the order that's significant, but the specific rules being used that can determine what needs to be changed.

Comment: `RewriteRule .* - [E=REQUEST_URI:%{REQUEST_URI}]` - Also, you should be setting an env var other that `REQUEST_URI` here (eg. `APACHE_REQUEST_URI`) to avoid conflicting with PHP's own `REQUEST_URI` superglobal (which can be different).